# memcached tomcat mysql on 1GB RAM

Tags: java, caching, memcached

I am new to memcached and caching in general. I have a java web application running on Ubuntu + Tomcat + MySQL on a VPS Server with 1GB of memory.

Does it make sense to add a memcached layer with about 256MB for caching? Will this be too much load on the server? Which is more appropriate caching rendered html pages or database objects?

Please advise.

Comment: Your latter question is a too broad subject and totaly depends on many factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to cache pages, don't use memcached, use [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/). However, there's a good chance that's not a great use of memory. Cacheing pages trades memory for computation and database work, but it does cost quite a lot of memory per page, so it's best for cases where the computation and database work needed to produce a single page amounts to a lot (or the pages are very small!). Also, consider that page cacheing won't be effective, or even possible, if you want to use per-user customisation on your pages (eg showing the number of items in a shopping cart). At least not without getting into some truly hairy shenanigans (edge-side includes, anyone?).

If you're not going to cache pages, and your app is on a single machine, then there's no point using memcached or similar. The point of cache servers like that is to make the memory on one machine work as a cache for another - like how a file server shares a disk, they're essentially memory servers. On a single machine, you might as well give all the memory to Java and cache objects on the heap.

Are you using an object-relational mapper? If so, see if it has any support for a second-level cache. The big three implementations (Hibernate, OpenJPA, and EclipseLink) all support in-memory caches. They're likely to do a much better job than you would if you did the cacheing yourself.

But, if you're not using a mapper, you have no choice but to do the cacheing yourself. There are extension points in LinkedHashMap for building LRU caches, and then of course there's the people's favourite, SoftReference, in combination with a HashMap. Plus, there are probably cache implementations out there you could download and use - i'd be shocked if there wasn't something in the Apache Commons libraries.

Comment: I tried page caching but couldnt do it because of user specific elements on the page. I use Hibernate. Currently using EHCache as a second level cache. So, i guess i am better off using EHCache for now.

Answer (score 0):

memcached won't add any noticeable load on your server, but it will be memory your app can't use.  If you only plan to have a single app server for a while, you're better off using an in-JVM cache.

As far *what* to cache, the answer falls somewhere in the middle of the above.  You don't want to cache exactly what's in your database and you certainly don't want to cache the final output.  You have a data model representation in your application that isn't exactly what's in the DB (e.g. a `User` object might be made up of multiple queries from a few different tables).  Cache that kind of thing as it's most reusable.

There's lots of info in the [memcached site](http://memcached.org/) that should help you understand and get going with caching in general and memcached specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to do that, why don't try a smaller size like 64 MB and see how that goes.  When you use more resources for the memcache, there is less for everything else.  You should try it and see what will give you the best performance.